# How to stop a service when a thread is doing work (without using Thread.Abort)

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have a service running some different tasks in a loop until the service is stopped.
However one of these tasks i calling a web service and this call can take several minutes to complete. I want to be able to stop the service instantly, 'cancelling' the web service call without calling `Thread.Abort` because that causes some strange behavior even if the only thing the thread is doing is calling this web service method.

How can i cancel or break from a synchronous method call (if it's even possible)?
Or should I try a different approach?

I have tried to use the `AutoResetEvent` and then calling `Thread.Abort` which is working fine in the below code sample, but when implementing this solution in the actual service I get some unexpected behavior probably because of what's going on in the external libraries I'm using.

`AutoResetEvent` and `Thread.Abort`:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MainProgram p = new MainProgram();
        p.Start();
        var key = Console.ReadKey();
        if (key.Key == ConsoleKey.Q)
            p.Stop();
    }
}

class MainProgram
{
    private Thread workerThread;
    private Thread webServiceCallerThread;
    private volatile bool doWork;

    public void Start()
    {
        workerThread = new Thread(() => DoWork());
        doWork = true;
        workerThread.Start();
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        doWork = false;
        webServiceCallerThread.Abort();
    }

    private void DoWork()
    {
        try
        {
            while (doWork)
            {
                AutoResetEvent are = new AutoResetEvent(false);
                WebServiceCaller caller = new WebServiceCaller(are);
                webServiceCallerThread = new Thread(() => caller.TimeConsumingMethod());
                webServiceCallerThread.Start();

                // Wait for the WebServiceCaller.TimeConsumingMethod to finish
                WaitHandle.WaitAll(new[] { are });

                // If doWork has been signalled to stop
                if (!doWork)
                    break;

                // All good - continue
                Console.WriteLine(caller.Result);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.Write(e);
        }
    }
}

class WebServiceCaller
{
    private AutoResetEvent ev;
    private int result;

    public int Result
    {
        get { return result; }
    }

    public WebServiceCaller(AutoResetEvent ev)
    {
        this.ev = ev;
    }

    public void TimeConsumingMethod()
    {
        try
        {
            // Simulates a method running for 1 minute
            Thread.Sleep(60000);
            result = 1;
            ev.Set();
        }
        catch (ThreadAbortException e)
        {
            ev.Set();
            result = -1;
            Console.WriteLine(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Can someone suggest a solution to this issue?

Comment: without knowing what you external libraries are doing any answer would be pure speculation... you could in theory just work with some "flag" which you check in that thread at points when it would be safe to "abort"...

Comment: Can you write your WebServiceCaller and thread mechanism so that it can be orphaned and left to die on its own when it returns?  Clear your doWork flag, stop waiting on the thread/event, set any callbacks to null, forget about it, carry on.   When the long web service call eventually returns and the thread sets its ref to null and terminates itself, no-one notices or cares, (sob..).

Comment: I could, but then my service (and it's process) would not be stopped completely until the WS call returns.

Comment: Oh - you want to completely end the whole service process - can you just call ExitProcess() then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is really this simple: Don't make calls that block for several minutes unless you want to block for several minutes. If there is no way to do a particular thing without blocking, potentially for several minutes, complain loudly to whoever wrote the code that imposes that painful requirement (or fix it yourself, if possible).

Once you've made the call, it's too late. You're committed. If the function you are calling doesn't provide a safe way to abort it, then there's no safe way.

Comment: You can execute the Blocking Call in a completely seperate thread and just kill that Thread if you need to stop it.

Comment: @CodingBarfield How do you know that's safe? What if you kill that thread while it holds a lock that a critical thread (say one doing writes to a file that is currently in an inconsistent state) needs in order to shut down cleanly?

Comment: Well, if there really is no other way around this then maybe I should look into another way of solving this.

Comment: @NicklasJepsen Can you avoid making the blocking call in the first place? Does the API you are using offer a non-blocking, limited-time blocking, asynchronous, or cancellable version? (If not, complain loudly to whoever provided it. A function that might block for minutes that is uncancellable and with no other way to get the same functionality is just bad design.)

Comment: I will look into avoid making the blocking call. I just wanted to know if there was a descent way to stop if from being executed. But I completely understand your point about bad API design and find another way to solve this (by making an async call).

Comment: Why not just forget about it?  Why bother stopping it if you don't have to?  It's blocked, so it's not like it's using a huge amount of resources. Just leave it alone so it can eventually die in peace.

Comment: @MartinJames I can't say for sure what the OP's issue is, but the usual problem is that you can't shut down other things because the "stuck thread" can become unblocked at any instant, potentially trying to access the very resources you would like to shut down. If that happens, you may fault rather than shutting down cleanly which is a potential disaster if parts of your clean shutdown code are critical.

Comment: I actually managed to make an async call and I think it is the most correct solution to the problem. Thanks for the input!

Comment: Another addition is to let the background thread acces resources that get 'locked up' after it should shut down. Even if the thread returns and tries to acces a shared resource it can not because its locked up.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: If the goal is to atomically determine whether a thread is in a safely-abortable state and kill it off if so, I would think one could have that thread, on startup, create an object, acquire a lock on it, and store a reference.  Then release the lock when safely killable and reacquire when not.  To kill the thread, make sure the reference is set, try to acquire a lock on it, and--if successful--kill the thread.  The lock will prevent the victim thread from leaving the region where it may safely be killed.

Answer (score 5):

Try this

```
public void Start()
{
    workerThread = new Thread(() => DoWork());
    doWork = true;
    workerThread.IsBackground = true;
    workerThread.Start();
}
```

> A thread is either a background thread or a foreground thread.
>   Background threads are identical to foreground threads, except that
>   background threads do not prevent a process from terminating. Once all
>   foreground threads belonging to a process have terminated, the common
>   language runtime ends the process. Any remaining background threads
>   are stopped and do not complete.

For more details see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.isbackground.aspx

Comment: Why have I not found this one while searching. This could definitely sound like a solution. I will try this one out and return with the result.

Comment: +1 I never considered that - I assumed that any thread in a service would be set as a background thread.

Comment: +1 as @MartinJames I also thought it would run in the background. However the solution I'm going for is running it async.

Answer (score 0):

As all you want to do is make one an asynchonrous web service call at a time and on each response make another call you can dispense with the worker thread and simply make an aynchronous call, register a callback and make another async call from the callback:

```
class Program
{
    private static WebServiceCaller.TCMDelegate _wscDelegate;
    private static readonly WebServiceCaller _wsCaller = new WebServiceCaller();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        _wscDelegate = _wsCaller.TimeConsumingMethod;

        MakeWSCallAsync();

        Console.WriteLine("Enter Q to quit");
        while (Console.ReadLine().ToUpper().Trim()!="Q"){}
    }

    public static void MakeWSCallAsync()
    {
        _wscDelegate.BeginInvoke(OnWSCallComplete, null);
    }

    public static void OnWSCallComplete(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Result {0}", _wscDelegate.EndInvoke(ar));

        MakeWSCallAsync();
    }
}

class WebServiceCaller
{
    public delegate int TCMDelegate();

    public int TimeConsumingMethod()
    {
        try
        {
            // Simulates a method running for 1 minute
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            return 1;
        }
        catch (ThreadAbortException e)
        {
            return -1;
        }
    }
}
```

No blocking (well, the console thread is blocking on ReadLine()) and no windows kernal mode sync objects (AutoResetEvent) which are [expensive](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/threads/waithandles.shtml).