# Terminating the application after closing the form

Tags: c#

I have written an application in C#. But even after closing the form, the application will be running. That is .exe and .vshost files will be still running. So i have used the following Code to terminate the application. But it is not terminating.

```
   public void Form1_Closing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        Process[] pArry = new Process[500];

        pArry = Process.GetProcesses();
        foreach (Process p in pArry)
        {
            string s1 = p.ProcessName;
            s1 = s1.ToLower();
            if ((s1.Equals("new_prj.vshost")))
            {
                p.Kill();
            }
        }
    }
```

My project name is new_prj. And if i write the same code snippet in Button_Click function, it works properly. But not working in form closing function. Has anybody come across the same problem?

Comment: I guess that does not work because the form is not really closed (maybe you just deactivate it or set the visibility to false or whatever) - in any case this is very ugly and hacky code ... don't use anything like this - see my answer.

Comment: Also, if you are going to do this, you should do it Form.Closed not Form.Closing. Closing means it's not closed yet!

Comment: I am pressing the 'X' button to close the form. Does it just hide the form instead of closing it? Then how to close it?

Answer (score 2):

Can you use this ?

```
Application.Exit();
```

Comment: Ya it works. But the problem is, its not entering the Form_Closing function.

Comment: Can you user ActiveForm.Close(); when closing the form?

Answer (score 2):

There can be several reasons for this. 
If it's a multithreaded application then you might have another thread running preventing the process from terminating.

Please provide some more details.

**EDIT**

I posted a similar question and and got some input about how to use threads. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9273480/how-to-stop-a-service-when-a-thread-is-doing-work-without-using-thread-abort).

Here is a some usefull code from an answer to the post:

```
public void Start()
{
    workerThread = new Thread(() => DoWork());
    doWork = true;
    workerThread.IsBackground = true;
    workerThread.Start();
}
```

Notice the `IsBackground = true;`.

Comment: Its a multithreaded application. I am even aborting all the threads in Form_Closing function. I guess its not entering the form closing function itself.

Comment: You should be careful when aborting the threads - you don't always know what kind of trouble that can bring and even if you abort the treads then it can take some time to happen.
Perhaps you should rethink the way you are using the threads and occasionally verify that if the thread should stop it's work, aka when you application needs to shutdown.

Comment: Also, if your threads are doing background work, make sure they're set up as background threads which should make them entirely subordinate to their parent process.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to quit your application from anywhere you can use `Environment.Exit()` but I would suggest to solve the problem with your form. If you post more of your code we might be able to find the problem.

Comment: Ya it works. But the problem is, its not entering the Form_Closing function.

Answer (score 0):

You can try Application.Exit too, but as Carsten said, you are trying to treat the symptom rather than the cause.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried simply using     Application.Exit()?